# issues with OpenERP installation

Tags: python, odoo

I am installing openerp at my local server, I have installed it and its dependences but after finishing its installation when i run server *'openerp-server'* and acces it using *0.0.0.0:8069/*. I got the following error

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 709, in get_list
    return db_list(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 88, in db_list
    dbs = proxy.list()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 31, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 104, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 90, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 295, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 351, in exp_list
    cr = db.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 477, in cursor
    return Cursor(self._pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 183, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 378, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20130211_002141-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 433, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "ghrix" does not exist
```

I haven't recognize this error.
One more thing , I haven't edit **OpenERP server configuration file** . And if I have to edit this file then what are those changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error indicates that OpenERP is trying to connect to the PostgreSQL database server using the "ghrix" user, which does not exist. This is probably the user under which you are starting the server.
If you have created a special database user for OpenERP you need to specify it on the command-line using `--db_user=DB_USER` (and in that case you probably also need `--db_host=localhost` and `--db-password=YOUR_PASSWORD`).
If you haven't created any database user yet, the easiest solution is probably to create one named `ghrix`, e.g.:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ createuser -s ghrix  # -s to make a super-user that can create DBs
```

**Note:** Use `./openerp-server --help` to see all possible startup parameters for the OpenERP server. You can also put the command-line options in a config file: just execute

```
$ ./openerp-server -s
```

and then edit the sample config file that is created in `$HOME/.openerp_serverrc`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question has been answered, the following is a concise tutorial on installing a production grade OpenERP Server, that also explains how to set up the database, manage access rights and configure your OpenERP installation:

http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/02/how-to-install-openerp-6-1-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

you should check two case

First case:

> $ sudo su - postgres $ createuser -s ghrix

second case
fill the db user and db password in

> /odoo/debian/odoo.conf

run odoo with this parameter

> ./odoo-bin -c /opt/odoo/debian/odoo.conf

If not resolved comment below i try to resolve it